# The custom SurfaceView cannot be displayed on Android 7.0 devices. The onCreate method is not executed

Tags: android, kotlin, surfaceview

The above is my custom code. It cannot be displayed properly on Android 7.0 phones and PDA devices. Is there any problem with my code? Please help me solve my doubts.

Currently, I have no solution because it only reproduces on Android 7.0 devices.

Everything works fine on non-Android 7.0 devices. Only on Android 7.0 devices, it cannot be displayed properly. I have not found any issue related to the inability to display SurfaceView on Android 7.0 on Stack Overflow.

The following is my code. Please help me check if there are any issues and how to solve them. Currently, I have no ideas.

```
class SurfaceLoadingView : SurfaceView, Runnable, Callback {

    constructor(context: Context?) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        initView()
    }

    private lateinit var mPaint: Paint
    private lateinit var mClearPaint: Paint
    private var control = 12

    // 子线程标志位
    private var isDestroy = false


    private fun initView() {
        mPaint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.WHITE
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            strokeWidth = SizeUtils.sp2px(3f).toFloat()
            isAntiAlias = true
        }
        mClearPaint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.parseColor("#7C7C7C")
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        }
        holder.addCallback(this)
        setZOrderOnTop(true)
        holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    }

    override fun run() {
        while (!isDestroy) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (control == 0) {
                    control = 12
                }
                val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
                draw()
                val spendTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
                try {
                    if (80 - spendTime > 0) {
                        Thread.sleep(80 - spendTime)
                    }
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                control--
            }
        }
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        isDestroy = false
        ThreadUtils.getSinglePool().execute(this)
    }

    override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        isDestroy = true
    }

    private fun draw() {
        val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
        if (canvas != null) {
            canvas.drawPaint(mClearPaint)
            for (i in 0..11) {
                mPaint.alpha = (((i + 1 + control) % 12 * 255) / 12)
                canvas.drawLine(
                    width / 2f,
                    height / 2f - SizeUtils.sp2px(7f),
                    width / 2f,
                    height / 2f - SizeUtils.sp2px(7f) * 2,
                    mPaint
                )
                canvas.rotate(30f, width / 2f, height / 2f)
            }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```